# Rocksdb background threads are working after deleting db instance

Tags: c++, c++11, background-thread, rocksdb

My start up method:

```
vector<ColumnFamilyDescriptor> columnFamilies = ...
DBOptions dbOptions(options);
std::vector<int32_t> ttls = ...
DBWithTTL* _db;
std::vector<ColumnFamilyHandle*> _handles;
Status status = DBWithTTL::Open(dbOptions, WORKING_DIRECTORY, columnFamilies, &_handles, &_db, ttls, false);
```

My shutdown method:

```
for (auto handle : _handles) {
    delete handle;
}
delete _db->GetBaseDB();
```

But after shutdown is completed, I'm still getting `merge` requests with stack under `rocksdb::DBImpl::BGWorkCompaction(void * arg)`, which of course fail because all column family handles were disposed of.

How can I mark any compaction or flushing to stop? Deleting db instance doesn't seem to be enough.